# Delete p tag inside <li> tags xslt 1

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to remove `<p> tags inside <li>` tags.
Example:

```
<ul><li id="62592d802d9bf64743a6103f"> <p> <u> <strong>WHAT IS CARRER DEVELOPMENT PLAIN ?</strong> </u> </p> </li></ul>
```

Desired output:

```
 <ul><li id="62592d802d9bf64743a6103f"><u> <strong>WHAT IS CARRER DEVELOPMENT PLAIN ?</strong> </u></li></ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following XSLT-1.0 template. The *Identity Template* just copies all elements as they are. The second template does essentially the same, but without copying the current element (here only for the `<p>` element).

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <!-- Identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p[ancestor::li]">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:template>
      
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you also want to remove the spaces/prettify the output, then add the following line at the top-level (just after `xsl:stylesheet`):

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
```

Comment: This doesn't work and throwing error Sequence normalization: Cannot process an attribute node. And also my requirement is to just delete the p tag inside the li tags.

Comment: I corrected my answer to only match _p_  elements with _li_ ancestors. I tested it with `xsltproc`, a standard conform XSLT-1.0 processor. P.S.: Changed the order of `node()|@*`.

Comment: Even i tried with ancestor but didn't work but now i tried with ur solution and it's working fine. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Glad I could help. Would be happy if you accept that answer.

Comment: Can you help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71996195/verify-href-has-a-valid-url-or-not-xslt-1?noredirect=1#comment127219728_71996195